# How to export all of the English out of Drupal, (we translate ourselves) and import it back into Drupal

Tags: drupal-7

We are using Internationalization (i18n) for drupal7.

We need to export all of the English out of Drupal, (we translate ourselves) and import it back into Drupal. We noticed that in the translation
interface we are able to Import and Export all the Blocks, Menus and Taxonomy, but we are unable to do that for the contents which are uploaded in the
content types. Is there any seperate modules available or is it possble to do that in the i18n module itself. Please clarify?

Comment: Maybe worth checking out: Translation Management Tool. (https://www.drupal.org/project/tmgmt)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe have a look at [Strongarm](https://www.drupal.org/project/strongarm) module which allows you to export administration variables as Features. I'm personally using this module to export the translations I made in i18n module.